# in graph api, using authorization_code to get access_token, but not return expire of refresh_token, how to get the refresh_token expire

Tags: graph, access-token, refresh-token

using authorization_code get access_token, it is the response of get access_token, but not get expire of refresh_token

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read Mail.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "EwBoA8l6BAAUO9chh8cJscQLmU+LSWpbnr0vmwwAAYVTxhn1SDP6wduXKXbHsiFqNsGBROCfKHzHwvbvr1pqrrNb2KLXUgHn2z2hkyKMrK7cuML5VuK0U6AmbOXKcJc6c0Sa7+q6JNWAsehnwysDZgAACBnZ52k6U4w1OAKX3xQz6Z/5iZtsU/FyM26dZZ7berNz1eH9ht2jyvi4uoPPPAytVeAhexqxdIKUto9kvL1Vi0eqJFeakX8R+/lnrg5vwfU7i55lrFfpGSJnHanK0dC7lvfsotUBay35dleRDOqQqhR5EQqrxFTrwVya0Lp6IKrSOhDNXW5lqCYsCRjg87zTZhBfGwRMtNgobe3d+Ne7KTO2hAbymuS3tvaHN9pNUUg7YPVITWL4bm2MEXzWEytj9fAw42k/LykMsJRH1aI66d8EpRqvcvqglEvz551GTaZewLIWSnzIUsTFHGofiW/XECPv6md4uFq2ToyGv7Nsb7Sv5dOoS9GjBxwtPEYQCPc7laJojj9aIWOhhRVjyKOHlx+0Ss4l1XtA3BZ40r/uLTsv3c8AAbAaqC9yc9PT6uuzcAjWevj6nhAZj5JmeiNr/euG6FE56SRPBraUVbuNoZV9G26BC47GQXKlGdWbyD3ivK77WiU0+yMFy522m9N1on3QO3GHe3sTeqbnqMDc741EZm6cWpwE5TIhXcNMI/CPraVWRRUPNRm/7nSqykAeL7khdd4O2QnuKwldcg7ZHpUGkwdBGO0rhX0dIu+mYrZ9YzFCugt6Y6QUOTb2ZE5DxAyjtHd5dEG/ukmsSl5LdxpLNZIdG3Ki7sPrij7gjLpU5f+qcezEgAPm2zVct+aHVJu8izS9tupxzQho4GU52uKbRIWjkxp/vcRrWCKOtDByKXE+v8LZcDXdZBLEgXUmDcC9dQI=",
    "refresh_token": "M.R3_BAY.-CZKuMZvNYim5kbvoyAOhzXf7vi26b8h8dy9dlHVmYz7ca849ZOY3OyKF!n!rBOtU*PsN24Wo7MCubbRYzzH0nfklhysmuSdBl3gxuhTYeQWlaHDYLRv9pyp1jqSYiRRKGXRJfP5cyyUPuA0qHd7VVA7aio9vWVGbOI0Yi!z6mCZpAo7c2Ifu*FAj"
}
```

Comment: i want to recreate  refresh_token if expire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a value you can get programmatically according to OAuth standards. The usual thing instead is to handle the invalid_grant error code in the client:

- Send the refresh token in renewal requests
- This will return a new access token for a while
- Eventually it will expire and you will get an invalid_grant in the 'error' response field